# How do you use the sum() aggregation in swift for firebase?

Tags: swift, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, aggregate

I need to get the sum of all the totalTime: Int values in the sessions collection in firebase with swift as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries), however I am not sure how to do it and I can't find it in the documentation:

```
   func sumTotalTime() async throws -> Int {
        guard let uid = self.userSession?.uid else {
            print("User not authenticated.")
            return 0
        }
        var sum = 0
        let query = db.collection("users/\(uid)/sessions")
        let sumQuery = query.aggregate([.sum("totalTime")])
        do {
          let snapshot = try await sumQuery.getAggregation(source: .server)
            print("this is the sum of all time", snapshot)
//            sum = ??
        } catch {
          print(error)
        }
        return sum
    }
```

This code appears to return something in the snapshot, but I am not sure how to use it or if it's even got the right data in it. How would you resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow there are no code samples for the sum and average functions for the mobile SDKs yet (I'm asking around for them), but here's an example from the [unit tests](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/90e24d0a48d7b5ecf77d2185c484e4a55a8a7878/Firestore/Swift/Tests/Integration/AggregationIntegrationTests.swift#L282):

```
func testAverageUnderflow() async throws {
 let collection = collectionRef()
 try await collection.addDocument(data: ["underflowSmall": Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude])
 try await collection.addDocument(data: ["underflowSmall": 0])

 let snapshot = try await collection.aggregate([AggregateField.average("underflowSmall")])
   .getAggregation(source: .server)

 // Average
 XCTAssertEqual(snapshot.get(AggregateField.average("underflowSmall")) as? Double, 0.0)
}
```

So it looks like you can get the sum from the snapshot with something like:

```
snapshot.get(AggregateField.sum("totalTime"))
```